# Azure Mobile App - Table Controller using Entity Data Model class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a Azure Mobile App project which by default created TodoItem table controller. I also have a DAL project which uses *EF6 Entity Data Model* which is referred in my other ASP.Net MVC project.

I wish to use the same DAL project in my app project instead redefining each entities again. I understand that for Table Controller, these entities need to be derive from **EntityData**. And the one in DAL project are not, e.g. as below

```
namespace DAL.Model
{
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;

   public partial class TodoItem
   {
      public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
      public string Text { get; set; }
      public Nullable<bool> Complete { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Am aware that I can inherit the DAL project using API Controller, but want to check possibility of using TableController in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is follow what [this example](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-use-existing-sql-database/) does. It has an existing model and uses DTOs to create a "mobile" version of them that does have the `EntityData` inheritance.

You can then create a map between your DAL project items and your Mobile Items.

For example:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<MobileOrder, Order>();
    cfg.CreateMap<MobileCustomer, Customer>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Order, MobileOrder>()
        .ForMember(dst => dst.MobileCustomerId, map => map.MapFrom(x => x.Customer.Id))
        .ForMember(dst => dst.MobileCustomerName, map => map.MapFrom(x => x.Customer.Name));
    cfg.CreateMap<Customer, MobileCustomer>();

});
```

You then create a domain manager to manage the logic between the two, and use that to create your Table Controller for your Mobile Service.